# Запятая в ССП с общей частью

Tags: запятые, ссп

> Согласно Корану, человек по своей природе является монотеистом(,) и таковая его натура в субстанциальном плане неизменна.

Нужна ли запятая в скобках? И почему?
Относится ли часть "согласно Корану" к обоим предложениям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второе придаточное предложение (утверждение) содержит ссылку на первое (слова *таковая его натура*), а первое, как сказано, верно согласно Корану. Верно ли оно вне Корана, в рамках этого  текста остается неизвестным. Поэтому второе утверждение можно рассматривать лишь в контексте ссылки на Коран. Вывод: текст составлен так, что слова "согласно Корану" являются общими для обоих придаточных, запятая не нужна.

Но я бы поспорил с точкой зрения автора. Не уверен, что Коран рассматривает мир под углом "неизменности натуры в субстанциальном плане".

Answer (score 1):

....**человек по своей природе является монотеистом, и таковая его натура в субстанциальном плане неизменна.**

Если это утверждение взято из Корана, то при наличии общего вводного слова в ССП запятая не нужна. В противном случае запятая ставится.